# How to prepare GrADS's .ctl file to convert grd file into .nc file in batch mode?

Tags: climate, rainfall, netcdf

I have lots of grd (GrADS) file and I want to convert those data into netCDF file using cdo. The operation needs all the corresponding ctl file and I will have to prepare all these. So, my question is  there any workaround for this using bash, python or R. Here is an example of ctl file:

```
*need to change the file name year*_rfp25.grd for each file
DSET /home/amit/climate_data/rf/year1901_rfp25.grd
TITLE Gridded rainfall
UNDEF -999.0
XDEF  135  LINEAR  66.5 0.25
YDEF  129  LINEAR  6.5 0.25
ZDEF   1 linear 1 1 
* CHANGE TDEF TO 366 FOR LEAP YEARS
TDEF 365  LINEAR 1jan1901 1DY 
VARS  1
rf 0 99 GRIDDED RAINFALL
ENDVARS
```

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.SE! Which information needs to be adapted in each `.ctl` file? Is there one file per year and the .ctl files differ only in line 2 (filename of grd file) and 9 (start date)?

Comment: @daniel.neumann you are right. Year and total number of days 365 /366 need to be adapted in each .ctl file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial n error I figured it out using the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

day_number () {
year=$1
leap="false"

if [ $((year % 4)) -ne 0 ] ; then
   :
elif [ $((year % 400)) -eq 0 ] ; then
     leap="true"
elif [ $((year % 100)) -eq 0 ] ; then
   : 
else

   leap="true"
fi
if [ "$leap" == "true" ];
then
   echo 366
else
   echo 365
 fi
}

for j in {1901..2015};
do
days=$(day_number j)
echo "DSET /home/amit/climate_data/rf/year${j}_rfp25.grd
TITLE Gridded rainfall
UNDEF -999.0
XDEF  135  LINEAR  66.5 0.25
YDEF  129  LINEAR  6.5 0.25
ZDEF   1 linear 1 1 
* CHANGE TDEF TO 366 FOR LEAP YEARS
TDEF ${days}  LINEAR 1jan${j} 1DY 
VARS  1
rf 0 99 GRIDDED RAINFALL
ENDVARS">year${j}_rfp25.ctl
done
```